# MongoDB - update property of subdocument where the string starts with certain text

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to update many subdocument array objects where property 'name' starts with 'Test:'

I need the new 'name' to be the current 'name' but updated with the 'Test:' part removed from the string.

I have already achieved it but not in a subdocument, this is how I got it to work in a document:

```
db.getCollection('test').updateMany(
{ name: { $regex: '^Test :' } },
[{ $set: { name: { $replaceOne: { input: "$name", find: 'Test : ', replacement: "" } } } }]
)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$map` to iterate through the array elements and and use `$mergeObjects` to update the field `name`

```js
db.collection.update({
  "arr.name": {
    $regex: "^Test :"
  }
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "arr": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$arr",
          "as": "a",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$a",
              {
                name: {
                  "$replaceOne": {
                    "input": "$$a.name",
                    "find": "Test : ",
                    "replacement": ""
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B7ZIPDurrV8)

Comment: Perfect thank you, I just had to use updateMany rather than update for all documents in the collection.